# How to get all elementIDs that begin with a substring

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="lists">
    <div class="list 1">
        <div id="productCheese">Cheese</div>
        <div id="productBread">Bread</div>
        <div id="productMilk">Milk</div>
        <div id="productEgg">Egg</div>
        <div id="addProduct">Add new product to list...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list 2">
        etc...
    </div>
</div>
```

And JavaScript: (I want to get **all** elements with an ID that begins with 'product', but the '*' doesn't work for me...)

```
var node = document.getElementById("product"*);

(And some unnecessary event listeners...)
```

Now my question is: how to get *all the elementIDs* that begin with 'product'?

Comment: "but the '*' doesn't work out for me" - that's because it's pseudo code. Where did you get the idea you could do `"string"*`?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Did you read the question? Your comment doesn't make sense, they **are** unique here.

Comment: @Utkanos It was just to show what I was trying to do... I already knew that is was wrong, but I didn't know what to type else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) will provide what you're looking for. They are used with `document.querySelector` and [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

In your case, you can specify the attribute id that starts with product:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=product]');
```

**Working example:**

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=product]');

console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<div class="lists">
    <div class="list 1">
        <div id="productCheese">Cheese</div>
        <div id="productBread">Bread</div>
        <div id="productMilk">Milk</div>
        <div id="productEgg">Egg</div>
        <div id="addProduct">Add new product to list...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list 2">
        etc...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you've got pseudo code there; `"product"*` is a parse error.

You need to use a selector via `querySelectorAll`.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="product"]');
```

This will return a [nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which you can then iterate over and do with what you will.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give an unique id to each div. Just give to them `class="product"` and use `document.querySelectorAll('.product')`

Comment: That is not what I want with the code. I want that you can click on the divs and then another screen pops up (every product has another screen) so I really need those different ID's

Comment: @Sacha Why can't you do `<div id="productCheese" class="product">`?

Comment: @Sacha just trying to show here that you can generalize the markup, there are multiple ways to achieve this, even write product id in separate attribute.

Answer (score 0):

i have test this code and get the desirable result

```js
var matches = [];
var searchEles = document.getElementById("listone").children;

for(var i = 0; i < searchEles.length; i++) {


    if(searchEles[i].id.includes('product')){

        matches[i]=searchEles[i];

    }

}
console.log(matches);
```

```html
<div class="lists">
    <div class="list 1" id="listone">
        <div id="productCheese">Cheese</div>
        <div id="productBread">Bread</div>
        <div id="productMilk">Milk</div>
        <div id="productEgg">Egg</div>
        <div id="addProduct">Add new product to list...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list 2">
        etc...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

with that way too!

```js
var IDs = [];

$("#list").find("div").each(function(){

if(this.id.includes('product')){
IDs.push(this.id); 
}

});

console.log(IDs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lists" id="list">
    <div class="list 1" id="listone">
        <div id="productCheese">Cheese</div>
        <div id="productBread">Bread</div>
        <div id="productMilk">Milk</div>
        <div id="productEgg">Egg</div>
        <div id="addProduct">Add new product to list...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list 2" id="listtwo">
<div id="productCheese">Cheese</div>
        <div id="productewqewewew">Bread</div>
        <div id="productrerereilk</div>
        <div id="producttrtytrut">Egg</div>
        <div id="addProductccc">Add new product to list...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```